# How to use Foreach data as "this"

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to loop through this data, to give value to each.

```
const key = Object.keys(response.data)
key.forEach((index,element) => {
    // let query = "this."+element
    this.element = response.data.element
});
```

the output should be

```
this.name = response.data.name
this.password= response.data.password
```

...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback

Comment: @DanielA.White The code uses an arrow function, that should access the correct `this`.

Comment: Array functions can also take a second parameter after the callback to be bound to `this`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach#Syntax One caveat though is you can only use real functions and not lambda functions to properly get `this` bound.

Comment: @DrewReese Not needed with an arrow function.

Comment: It's not needed normally, agreed, but in the context of an array function callback, it won't work. Try it.

Comment: @DrewReese It would be if you used an old-style function, but arrow functions inherit the caller's `this`. See the working example in my answer.

Comment: @Barmar, yes, that works because it is inheriting the `this` from the `MyClass` enclosure you created. OP's question didn't specify what the parent was, so in isolation the `this` in their snippet is unclear. My point was that within this isolation you can pass a reference to an object you want to be the `this` within the callback if you don't want it to inherit the caller's `this`. It is right in the docs I linked. Think utility function versus anonymous callback.

Comment: @DrewReese It wasn't clear that you were talking about passing something *other* than the caller's `this` object.

Comment: The question is clear that he wants to set properties of the caller's `this` -- see the desired result at the end.

Comment: @Barmar I didn't say anything about the caller's `this`, or any specific `this` at all, just that the array::forEach API allows a second parameter to be passed *as* `this` for use in the callback, with link to source. Agree to disagree I suppose, but the OP's `this` could literally be anything, doesn't have to just be the caller, and it was clear to me OP was asking how to assign/access `this` in the callback.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have several problems with your code, neither of which has to do with accessing `this`.

First, you have ths arguments in the wrong order in the callback. The first argument is the element, the second is the index (maybe you're used to jQuery -- it uses the opposite order in its `.each()` and `.map()` methods).

Second, you're not using the element properly. `.element` means to access the property literally named `element`, it doesn't use the value of the variable `element`. You have to use `[element]` to access a property dynamically; see [Dynamically access object property using variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244896/dynamically-access-object-property)

```
const key = Object.keys(response.data)
key.forEach((element) => {
    this[element] = response.data[element]
});
```

```
class MyClass {
  copyProps(response) {
    const key = Object.keys(response.data)
    key.forEach((element) => {
      this[element] = response.data[element]
    });
  }
}

obj = new MyClass;
obj.copyProps({
  data: {
    name: "MyName",
    age: 10
  }
});
console.log(obj);
```

You could also use `Object.assign()` to copy properties:

```
Object.assign(this, response.data);
```

Comment: Thank you Very much for the answer, works!